# Could Muggles enter Diagon Alley from Leaky Cauldron?

Tags: harry-potter

Courtesy of [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26804/976), I found the a bit of [weird information on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Places_in_Harry_Potter#The_Leaky_Cauldron) (currently un-cited):

> **The Leaky Cauldron**
>
> **The pub serves as a way of entering into Diagon Alley from the Muggle world for Muggle-borns and their parents (both of whom, until the first letter from Hogwarts, have no magical knowledge or means of entering)**. The rear of The Leaky Cauldron opens onto a chilly little courtyard, in which a particular brick must be tapped three times to open a path to Diagon Alley.

But from what I can see, Muggleborns and their parents wouldn't be able to enter from Leaky Cauldron, because - based on what I can tell - that **requires one to use a wand**:

> **He {{Hagrid}} tapped the wall three times with the point of his umbrella.**
> The brick he had touched quivered – it wriggled – in the middle, a small hole appeared – it grew wider and wider – a second later they were facing an archway large enough even for Hagrid, an archway on to a cobbled street which twisted and turned out of sight.

**Is there some canon information confirming the Wikipedia assertion that Muggle parents and not-yet-wand-owning Muggleborns could enter Diagon Alley from the courtyard behind Leaky Cauldron?**

Comment: You mentioned in your comment at [is the Leaky Cauldron the only physical entrance to Diagon Alley](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/is-the-leaky-cauldron-the-only-physical-entrance-exit-for-diagon-alley) that there are no other known entrances, and we would expect Muggles cannot Floo ... so I imagine Diagon Alley would have to be the entrance for the Muggle parents and Muggleborn students. Just food for thought! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - I'm thinking something to the effect of needing a wizarding "doorman" there for pre-September shopping days. OR that there's another entrance I'm not aware of (what my answer said wasn't that there are no others - just that I don't know any others)

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing Hermione's parents inside some shop in Diagon Alley with Lucious Malfoy frothing at to the trio

Comment: If muggle born children come along with their parents and have their shopping list/invitation from Hogwarts with them another wizard could let them in. If it's not someone like Malfoy their running into off course. Maybe it's a task for the tenant of the Leaky Cauldron.

Comment: @KharoBangdo they were exchanging muggle money with wizard money in Gringotts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I think the barkeeper is responsible for getting lost travellers to Diagon Alley.**

Although Muggle-borns (and their Muggle parents) are the most obvious, there are plenty of other people who might want to get to Diagon Alley who do have a wand, but wouldn’t know how to get in. Unless you know the exact brick sequence, you’d be a bit stuck.

Presumably he or she just keeps an eye out for anybody looking lost, especially children with confused-looking parents, and offers to help them out.

This isn’t explicit in the canon, but I think it’s strongly hinted. Here are two examples:

- When Dumbledore explains to Riddle how to get his school things, he tells him how to get to the pub, but not how to proceed beyond that. Instead, he tells him to ask for the barkeeper:

  > Dumbledore handed Riddle the envelope containing his list of equipment, and, after telling Riddle exactly how to get to the Leaky Cauldron from the orphanage, he said, ‘You will be able to see it, although Muggles around you – non-magical people, that is – will not. Ask for Tom the barman – easy enough to remember, as he shares your name –’
  >
  > — *Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 13 (*The Secret Riddle*)
- In some new Pottermore information about Diagon Alley (spoiler text because it’s part of the 12 Days of Christmas promotion), it sounds like the barkeeper lets people into Diagon Alley:

  > He further agreed to give the landlord of the day responsibility for letting people into Diagon Alley from his back yard, for the shops beyond the pub were now also in need of magical protection.

Comment: It's worth explicitly noting in the answer, that in that case any muggle who can a) find Leaky Cauldron (or be lead there) and b) give a convincing story to Tom can enter Diagon Alley

Comment: Explicit enough for me :)

Comment: Given what Dumbledore says to the young Tom Riddle, I suspect that any Muggle who can even *see* the Leaky Cauldron is at least slightly less Muggle than most - Hermione's parents could see it, but they were at least magical enough to have a child who could use magic, and it's possible that Hermione saw it and showed it to them, at which point they became able to see it - rather like the Fidelius Charm, where Grimmauld Place was invisible to Harry until he was told it was there.